# Post to facebook status with a URL / GET request? (or post)

Tags: facebook

I rather expect that this might be impossible - but I was wonderring if it was possible to post a facebook status via passing in a URL.

Something to the effect of

```
 http://facebook.com/?status=<URL ENCODED STRING>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Wow.  Almost a full year since I asked this question.

As an FYI and for my own future reference, I did eventually discover how to do this.

```
 http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<message text>
 https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<message>
 http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<url>&title=<title>&summary=<description>&source=<source>
```

Google plus does not have a good option to use this method in desktop, but you can use their mobile URL

```
 https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=<message>
```

Comment: the facebook URL should read `u=<url to share>&t=<message text>`

Comment: What a boss, four useful bits in one post. You saved me from searching various developer sites looking for the right words to use on each of them. Thanks!

Comment: Incredibly helpful - thanks for posting the solution to your own question.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer appears to work as of now. The URL is populated, but the message is not. :(

Comment: As James mentioned, it doesn't seem to be possible to use the link above to publish text. Anybody found a workaround? I'd like to propose to my users a link and text.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix : use **&quote=** rather than **&t=**

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution useful also ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584197/sharer-link-with-parameter-in-url))

```
var facebook_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?'+
  'u='+encodeURIComponent('http://google.com/?q=bla')+
  '&amp;t='+encodeURIComponent('Some Page Title');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin CURL converter in the Graph API that gets you all you need.