# Sharer link with parameter in URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I have a popup window with a Facebook [custom share link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>
```

How can I use a url `u` with a parameter like `http://google.com/?q=bla`? It looks like facebook always cut of the parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should URL encode the parameters.

```
var facebook_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?'+
  'u='+encodeURIComponent('http://google.com/?q=bla')+
  '&amp;t='+encodeURIComponent('Some Page Title');
```