# Making a facebook status post using a URL/GET request

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am trying to make a windows phone app using cocos2d-x WP8 port. 
I wanted to post the final score of the player on Facebook if he presses the Facebook share button in the app.
So I tried the method explained here:
[Post to facebook status with a URL / GET request? (or post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703363/post-to-facebook-status-with-a-url-get-request-or-post)

The link for twitter is working fine, but for facebook, the text that I want to share does not appear in the text area of post. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook sharer to this date is a resurrected version of the sharer from 2011. The only possible parameter to set is the `u` parameter. Fix the metadata of the URL being referenced to modify title data (i.e. you must own the URL to modify for use with sharer.php, otherwise you will be forced to use the title the owner of the URL used).

Comment: Hmmmm, Okay. But What if I wanted to post a URL along with some text in the status. Is there any other way instead of using sharer ?

Comment: I just want a click-able link, does not need any title or image with the link.

Comment: @Wajahat you will need to use a Facebook plugin or the Official api.