# how to get round/circular facebook share button

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-like, facebook-share

I am looking for a way to implement round facebook share button just like how its done [here](http://blog.myfitnesspal.com/who-drinks-most-on-super-bowl-sunday/).
I am able to implement standard facebook share with rectangular button.

Comment: You can use any kind of link/button/image you like … all you have to do is call the FB Share dialog when that thing is clicked, and how that is done is described in sufficient detail in their documentation.

Comment: it requires using facebook id and app_id

Comment: will there be a count value for all the likes or share? I mean if i put an image tag for the circular fb inside an anchor tag, and on the anchor tag put an onclick which calls the FB.ui()....how to get the total likes or share?

Comment: No – but that wasn’t in the version that you linked to and asked for a solution _“just like” it_ either. (But it could be implemented by querying that value from the API via JavaScript.)

Comment: I tried FB.ui() its giving me this error 'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.'

Comment: Countless people before you have encountered that error _and_ asked about it already … so please do some _research_. (Or go and actually _read_ what the message tells you – the solution is already included in it.)

Comment: Has a solution to this been found? This seems like a simple problem but there's not a straight forward solution, except "go read through a ton of documentation." To expect someone to do that first for each and every simple problem they have could take too much time. Is it taboo to paste code examples? That seems like it would be the very fastest way to solve problems of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions:

-> Using an image

-> Using this very usefull frameworks : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ .
Put the icons in a div (50px * 50px) and just border-radius in CSS !

Comment: I have tried using an image tag, but i am so far only able redirect to facebook page.....could you possibly give me a simple code example on how to implement it?

Comment: You need to use the Facebook API, but you can use this link too :
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=LINK_TO_SHARE

Comment: the link you've provided works, thanks, but it doesn't open a dialog...it redirects my main page to facebook share

Comment: If my answer works, don't forget to check my answer :)

Comment: So you can read this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters

The last solution (but bad solution) is using standart facebook share button (rect), don't display it (in css) and make it float on your button.

Comment: your answer works, but its not what exactly what i was looking for....or not the exact correct answer, but still...i guess, it works so.....thanks....

Comment: The best way is using the API facebook developers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api

Comment: I am currently looking at the FB API, will there be a count value for all the likes or share....