# How share from Homepage several Posts each with own Screenshot, but all have one URL? Facebook, Google+, Twitter, Pinterest

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html, share-button

I have at Homepage several blocks, in each block are several Posts and each Post has own Screenshot.

For Example:      https://jsfiddle.net/6jrvyzzo/4/, if you hover on share button, you can see, what I want to do.

I have found [Has Facebook sharer.php changed to no longer accept detailed parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters), `facebook - sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=EXAMPLE&p[summary]=EXAMPLE&p[url]=EXAMPLE&p[images][0]=EXAMPLE`, where I can customize, what I want to share, but Facebook no longer supports custom parameters. If I do this with Open Graph parameters, then each Post can not have as Shared own Screenshot and Url to Block Page, while share Renderer gets Open Graph parameters from that url, where shared Item is linked. I need this for Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Pinterest.

Looking forward to your ideas

Comment: `<a class="share-icon facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating your posts with a custom made Content Management System(CMS), you will be able to use the Facebook sharer to share the link to each of the posts in the blocks.

For instance:

Block 1

```
1. {Post 1:Title} {Post 1:Excerpt} {Post 1:Link To Post} {Post 1:Sharer - Have the link to post here}

2. {Post 2:Title} {Post 2:Excerpt} {Post 2:Link To Post} {Post 2:Sharer - Have the link to post here}
```

You can use Social Media Share generator like: https://simplesharingbuttons.com/

Comment: Thanks Brian, but this can't help me. I need, that if anyone shares the " Post 1 " from " Block 1 " e.g. on Facebook, then must users see on Facebook Image(screenshot) of " Post 1 " and URL of " Block 1 Page ", after click on it, user must go to " Block 1 Page " and not to " Post 1 page ".