# When sharing post on facebook- not redirecting back to the site

Tags: php, facebook

I getting this after share `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_`.
Found question on stackoverflow but without solution.
The share working properly, all works except return to example.com after sharing. 
here my code how I sharing to the facebook:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . urlencode("http://www.example.com/share/".$fbUser . "/&app_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/"); ?>">Share Vadim</a>
```

please advise.
How to redirect after seccufull sharing back to example.com ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969530/6140684) out.

Comment: if facebook not support custom variables, how to redirect back to my site?

Comment: Through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog). Using the FB.ui() and inserting the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharer.php is [no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters/22969530#22969530).

I've made this function so try using it by modifying however you like it :
(use it in an `onclick` for example)

```
function fb_share() {
        // facebook share dialog
        FB.ui( {
            method: 'share', // Methord is share - there are different methods
            title: '<?php echo $mTitle;?>',
            name: 'Simple Text',
            href: '<?php echo $mURL; ?>',
            picture: '<?php echo $rooDir . $mImg;?>',
           // caption: '<?php echo $mCaption; ?>',
            description: '<?php echo $mDescription; ?>'
        }, function( response ) {
            // do nothing
        } );

}
```

Parameters and methods can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).